# Time out when using system cmd in perl

Tags: perl, remote-access, psexec

I'm using PSEXEC to run remote process with `system($CMD)` in perl.

I have a computer (lets call it-#1) that runs system `cmd`, and another computer (lets call it-#2), which "receives" commands from computer #1.

Sometimes the process in the second computer (#2) gets stuck.

How can I set a timeout to the system `cmd` in computer #1 that will force-terminate the cmd after several minutes?

---

thanks for the answers, but:
i'm tring to do somthing very simple, I have 2 perl files.
file#1 that counting seconds 1 to 10. (+print to the screen)
file#2-Timeout file that cal file#1 (system command) that should terminate file #1 after 5 sec.

the results...:
timeout occurred, but process #1 still running...

file#2

```
$timeout=5;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm $timeout;
    $nread = system('F:\perl1.pl');
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    print "process terminated\n";}
else {
    # didn't
}
```

file#1

```
$i=0;
while($

    i<10){
    sleep(1);
    $i++;

print "$i\n";
}
```

CMD window results:

```
C:\>F:\perl2.pl
1
2
3
4
process terminated

C:\>5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: [`perldoc -q timeout`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-timeout-a-slow-event%3f)

Answer (score 4):

Let [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) handle that for you.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );

run \@cmd, timeout( 120 )
   or die "cat: $?";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) in your situation:

> If you want to use `alarm` to time out a `system` call you need to use an
>   `eval`/`die` pair. You can't rely on the `alarm` causing the system call to
>   fail with `$!` set to `EINTR` because Perl sets up signal handlers to
>   restart `system` calls on some systems. Using `eval`/`die` always works,
>   modulo the caveats given in [Signals in `perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals).
>
> ```
> eval {
>     local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
>     alarm $timeout;
>     $nread = sysread SOCKET, $buffer, $size;
>     alarm 0;
> };
> if ($@) {
>     die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
>     # timed out
> }
> else {
>     # didn't
> }
> ```

Comment: Here's an example where [`eval/die` doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8452445/455789).