# Unable to handle exception handling on a Psexec command in perl

Tags: perl, cmd, psexec

I am trying to exit the `for` loop if the `psexec` command fails or more importantly if it takes more time , i am using `Time::Out` module in this program , but the `psexec` command does not exit ,am i  using it wrong? Is there any other way to deal with this situation.

```
#$nb_secs means number of seconds
  for my $host1 (@servers){
        timeout $nb_secs => sub {
                 # do stuff that might timeout.
                $returnFileNames=`psexec \\\\$host1 cmd /c "dir /s 
                 d:\\dd\` ;
        }; 

        next if $@;
}
```

Comment: What OS is this running on? the documentation for `Time::Out` says `alarm(2) doesn't interrupt blocking I/O on MSWin32, so 'timeout' won't do that either.`

Comment: @Chris Doyle it is running on windows server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various reasons why a `SIGALRM` will not get delivered to a process, and you have discovered one of them. A workaround is the [poor man's alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452445/perl-alarm-with-subprocess/8452732#8452732) -- run a separate process in the background to monitor the long running process and to kill it after some time has expired. On Windows and with a command where you need to capture the output, it would look something like this:

```
# $pid is the id of the process to monitor
my $pid = open my $proc_fh, '-|', "psexec \\\\$host1 cmd /c "dir /s d:\\dd\";

my $pma = "sleep 1,kill(0,$pid)||exit for 1..$nb_secs;"
        . "kill -9,$pid;system 'taskkill /f /pid $pid >nul'";
my $pma_pid = system 1, $^X, "-e", $pma;

# read input from the external process.
my $returnFilenames;
while (<$proc_fh>) {
    $returnFilenames .= $_;
}
close $proc_fh;
```

The poor man's alarm is a little program with two parts. The first part counts up to `$nb_secs` seconds and terminates if the monitored process is no longer running (if `kill 0,$pid` returns a false value). The second part of the program, if it is reached, terminates the monitored process. In this instance, we try two different ways (`kill -9 ...` and `system 'taskkill /f ...'`) to terminate the process.